# GitHub with HTTP protocol

Tags: git, http, github, protocol, network-protocols

[I read that](http://gist.github.com/grawity/4392747/aa2ac0e7553ecf0baa24eea2709ff6574d55a9c0)

> HTTP, aka `http://github.com`
>   Doesn't work with GitHub anymore

However it seems to work for me

```
$ git clone http://github.com/antirez/redis
Cloning into 'redis'...
remote: Counting objects: 26084, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9644/9644), done.
remote: Total 26084 (delta 19341), reused 22821 (delta 16228)
Receiving objects: 100% (26084/26084), 6.10 MiB | 916.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (19341/19341), done.
Checking connectivity... done
```

I understand the security implications, but I would like to know the status of using HTTP protocol with GitHub.

Comment: My mistake, my mind was was still in client certificate athentication. Your right, GIT is unable to run with public keys over http, but requires the backend of SSH to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
From: "Robert Sese (GitHub Staff)"

That's correct, we don't support git operations over HTTP.  If you add the verbose 
curl flag to your clone, you should see a redirect to HTTPS in the output:

GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone http://github.com/antirez/redis
```